# What is the Action and Reducer syntax to update state collection/array from an NgRX effect?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have an NgRX state:

```
import { Item } from './item';

export interface FeatureAState {
    items: Item[];
}
```

And an action (`'[featureA] Add Item'`) that will add an Item object to an array of Items on my store. I'd like to update this collection via a background effect after each item is added.

```
export const addItem = createAction(
    '[featureA] Add Item',
    (item: Item = { id: 3, title: 'Duff McKagen' }) => ({ item })
);
```

I have created an effect to trigger after the reducer has added the item:

```
updateItems$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType('[featureA] Add Item'),
    concatMap(() => this.myService.doSomeWork()
        .pipe(
            map(updatedItems => ({ type: '[featureA] Updated', payload: updatedItems }))
        ))
));
```

From my understanding this requires `myService.doSomeWork()` to return an Observable? For now I have hard-coded the return to be an Observable created from a new array, so I'm expecting the store items to change to this new array once the effect is finished and the `'[featureA] Updated'` action is handled by the reducer.

```
export class MyserviceService {

  doSomeWork() {
    return of([{ id: 6, title: 'Peter Parker' }]);
  }
}
```

So I now need an action to handle the effect results and update the store? But I don't know how to write the Action or Reducer for this.

```
export const updatedItems = createAction(
    '[featureA] Updated',
    props<{ items: Item[] }>()
);

// Also tried...

export const updatedItems = createAction(
    '[featureA] Updated',
    (items: Item[]) => ({ items }) // don't understand what I'm doing here, but I guess this action needs to pass through the output of `myService.doSomeWork()` (an Observable mapped to an Action via concatMap()?) for the Reducer to handle?
);
```

```
on(updatedItems, (state, { updatedItems }) => ({
    ...state,
    items: updatedItems // I suspect this is not correct, or the 'updatedItems' action is not passing through the correct object
}))

The error I seem to be getting is `ERROR in src/app/featureA/state/featureA.reducer.ts(11,32): error TS2339: Property 'updatedItems' does not exist on type '{ items: Item[]; } & TypedAction<"[featureA] Updated"> & { type: "[featureA] Updated"; }'.`
```

Comment: Add your state interface to the question

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `updatedItems`, you should use `items` since you're passing that in your action payload.

```
on(updatedItems, (state, { items }) => ({
    ...state,
    items
}))
```

Comment: Are the two `createAction` statements equivalent in terms of passing the items to the reducer, so the reducer syntax would be identical for each? I have updated the reducer with the above change, but after the reducer runs both actions I end up with just the "featureA" property (the feature state) but no items property at all.

Comment: Does the "items" variable in my reducer need the same name as what is provided in the action? I thought they'd both be local.

Comment: I was actually passing 'payload' in my actions payload, so this didn't work, but certainly led me to figure out what was wrong by questioning my properties so thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem was here:

```
updateItems$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType('[featureA] Add Item'),
    concatMap(() => this.myService.doSomeWork()
        .pipe(
            map(updatedItems => ({ type: '[featureA] Updated', payload: updatedItems })) // <= HERE
        ))
));
```

I didn't understand `payload` is just a property for my action and doesn't have to be called `payload`. As it was I was passing 'payload' to the action, but not referencing it in the action or reducer. In fact I didn't event need to reference it in the Action either. So this will update the store based on my service response:

```
export const updatedItems = createAction(
    '[featureA] Updated'
);
```

```
on(updatedItems, (state, { payload }) => ({
    ...state,
    items: payload
}))
```

As will this:

```
updateItems$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType('[featureA] Add Item'),
    concatMap(() => this.myService.doSomeWork()
        .pipe(
            map(updatedItems => ({ type: '[featureA] Updated', items: updatedItems }))
        ))
));
```

```
on(updatedItems, (state, { items }) => ({
    ...state,
    items
}))
```

I get a Typescript error though, which can be fixed by updating the Action with either of these:

```
export const updatedItems = createAction(
    '[featureA] Updated',
    props<{ items: Item[] }>()
);

// or

export const updatedItems = createAction(
    '[featureA] Updated',
    (items: Item[]) => ({ items })
);
```

In the end I've gone with this, which seems more explicit about what's going on:

```
updateItems$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType('[featureA] Add Item'),
    concatMap(() => this.myService.doSomeWork()
        .pipe(
            map(updatedItems => ({ type: '[featureA] Updated', payload: updatedItems }))
        ))
));
```

```
export const updatedItems = createAction(
    '[featureA] Updated',
    (payload: Item[]) => ({ payload })
);
```

```
on(updatedItems, (state, { payload }) => ({
    ...state,
    items: payload
}))
```